# How to prevent page refresh on browser back to page generated by ajax call

Tags: javascript

- My application has a search results page and details page.
- The results are different on every page refresh.
- The user can refine the search which generates ajax call, the results are updated, the URL is updated and window.history is updated.
- When the user clicks on a result link and navigates to the details and then back to the results page using the browser back button the expected behavior is to see the previous results, but the search result page is being refreshed and the results are different.
- It works as expected if no refinements were made, and the results are from a full page refresh.

Is there a way to push the ajax call result? 
I don't understand where the actual state of the result page is stored. Because history.state has the URL of the page.

Comment: Why would your search results be different every time? You should be able to store all parameters needed to search in your URL. You could store the previous search results in local storage but I really think your search results should be constant.

Comment: If you're using a single page application, then its simply a matter of keeping a cache of position of the search results. If not, then either you can use local storage to retain position or cookies. Using cookies for this kind of logic is a code smell. Local storage is preferable.

Comment: I would prefer to use the same mechanism as window.history uses to go back. Because if no refinements are made the full state of the page is stored somewhere and restored without page refresh @SteveTomlin

Comment: @SpeedOfRound, there is some randomness to the search results, that the business rules